# How to use import statement for custom modules in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python programming and writing simple helloworld program by using python 3.3 on windows environoment.The helloworld program is saved as hello.py.  So how can i use it in another module. I tried sys.path.append and give path of my save file but its not working. 
Can somebody tell me do i have to set Environment variable in windows xp

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this way:

```
import sys
```

then:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"X")
```

Where `X` is the directory you want to import from.

After that you just need to import your custom module:

```
import X
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 3):

There is a directory `DIR` containing our module `X`: `/DIR/X`

```
import sys    
sys.path.insert(0,"DIR")
import X
```

This imports the module e.g. X =`hello`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make your `hello.py` a module you need to create a file named `__init.py__` in the hello.py folder.

Take a look at the Python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).