# Installing Boto3 with Different botocore

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, github, pip

[Boto3 is using their own botocore](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/requirements.txt) (which makes sense).

However, the [exiting botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore) doesn't support the new [Transcribe API](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/) which I would really like to use.

I'd like to use [this forked botocore](https://github.com/vedant/botocore/tree/add-amazon-transcribe) which implemented the transcribe service.

What are the steps I should follow in order to install Boto3 with the forked botocore?

Is there a simple way to achieve this using `pip install` ?

Comment: Ask the creator of that fork what he/he would suggest as the simplest way to use it? Have them add that info to the readme.

Comment: Try this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485933/how-to-use-import-statement-for-custom-modules-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

1. Fork the original repo (boto3)
2. Edit `requirments.txt` to use the dependency you need (other botocore)
3. pip install your forked repo

Worked for me